# Firebase: ...node_modules\firebase\app\dist\app\index has no exported member 'User'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, angularfire

I just upgraded my firebase+angularfire package from 7 to 9 after I upgraded to angular 13, adapted some stuff to use the `@angular/fire/compat/*` import path.

But I've several places where I was using the `firebase.User`, by example, to initialize a profile based on a `firebase.User`:

```
private createProfile(user: firebase.User | null): UserProfile | null {
    if (!user) {
      return null;
    }
    return {
      displayName: user.displayName ?? '',
      email: user.email ?? '',
      photoURL: user.photoURL ?? '',
      uid: user.uid,
      userIncomplete: !user.displayName || !user.email || !user.photoURL,
    };
  }
```

But now it doesn't find the `firebase.User`:

```
Error: src/app/auth/state/auth.service.ts:60:40 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index"' has no exported member 'User'.

60   private createProfile(user: firebase.User | null): UserProfile | null {
```

Any idea where I can import this User from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to add:

> import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

Answer (score 0):

i have imported it from `modular` package like this

```
import { Auth, User } from '@angular/fire/auth';

public user: Observable<User | null>;
```

Please check this [link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/samples/modular/src/app/auth/auth.component.ts) in git

Firebase also changed its interface from version 9 [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error was a path.You need to import it with

`import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/firebase.app.module';`

Instead of
`import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire`;